# Removing list item if not in another list - python

Tags: python

Here is my situation. 
I have a list of Person objects.

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name="", age=):
        self.name = name
        self.uid = str( uuid.uuid4( ) )
        self.age = age
```

My UI contains a treeview displaying these items. In some cases users can have a instance of the same person if they want. I highlight those bold to let the user know it's the same person.

[image: ![enter image description here]

THE PROBLEM
When a user deletes a tree node I then need to know if I should remove the actual object from the list. However if another instance of that object is being used then I shouldn't delete it.

My thoughts for a solution. 
Before the delete operation takes place, which removes just the treenode items, I would collect all persons being used in the ui.

Next I would proceed with deleting the treeview items.

Next take another collection of objevst being used in the ui.

Laslty compare the two lists and delete persons not appearing in second list.

If I go this solution would I be best to do a test like

```
for p in reversed(original_list):
    if p not in new_list:
        original_list.remove(p)
```

Or should I collect the uid numbers instead to do the comparisons rather then the entire object?

The lists could be rather large.

Herr is the code with my first attempt at handling the remove operation. It saves out a json file when you close the app.

https://gist.github.com/JokerMartini/4a78b3c5db1dff8b7ed8

This is my function doing the deleting.

```
def delete_treewidet_items(self, ctrl):
        global NODES
        root = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()

        # delete treewidget items from gui
        for item in self.treeWidget.selectedItems():
            (item.parent() or root).removeChild(item)

        # collect all uids used in GUI
        uids_used = self.get_used_uids( root=self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem() )

        for n in reversed(NODES):
            if n.uid not in uids_used:
                NODES.remove(n)
```

Comment: What is your code for adding to the UI ? What is your code that creates a person and uses the same instance ?

Comment: I see - so really the problem is that you have 'items' and you can't get the persons from them - the usual problem with UI list controls. Does your control permit you to somehow connect the items to the persons ? Aka can you get from the `item` to the `person` ? EDIT: of course you can - you have that CustomTreeNode which basicaly wraps a perdon (why calling a person person data) ? Refactor your code based on my answer and post back - basically you can chop off a few lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not really posted enough code but from what I can gather:

```
import collections
import uuid

class Person():
    def __init__(self, name="", age=69):
        self.name = name
        self.uid = str( uuid.uuid4( ) )
        self.age = age

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Person) and self.uid == other.uid
    def __ne__(self, other): return self != other # you need this

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.uid)

# UI --------------------------------------------------------------------------
persons_count = collections.defaultdict(int) # belongs to your UI class
your_list_of_persons = []  # should be a set

def add_to_ui(person):
    persons_count[person] += 1
    # add it to the UI

def remove_from_ui(person):
    persons_count[person] -= 1
    if not persons_count[person]: your_list_of_persons.remove(person)
    # remove from UI
```

So basically:

> before the delete operation takes place, which removes just the treenode items, I would collect all persons being used in the ui.

No - you have this info always available as a module variable in your ui - the `persons_count` above. This way you don't have to copy lists around.

Remains the code that creates the persons - then your list (which contains *distinct* persons so should be a *set*) should be updated. If this is done in `add_to_ui` (makes sense) you should modify as:

```
def add_to_ui(name, age):
    p = Person(name, age)
    set_of_persons.add(p) # if already there won't be re-added and it's O(1)
    persons_count[person] += 1
    # add it to the UI
```

To take this a step further - you don't really need your original list - that is just `persons_count.keys()`, you just have to modify:

```
def add_to_ui(name, age):
    p = Person(name, age)
    persons_count[person] += 1
    # add it to the UI

def remove_from_ui(person):
    persons_count[person] -= 1
    if not persons_count[person]: del persons_count[person]
    # remove from UI
```

So you get the picture

**EDIT:** here is delete from my latest iteration:

```
def delete_tree_nodes_clicked(self):
    root = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()
    # delete treewidget items from gui
    for item in self.treeWidget.selectedItems():
        (item.parent() or root).removeChild(item)
        self.highlighted.discard(item)
        persons_count[item.person] -= 1
        if not persons_count[item.person]: del persons_count[item.person]
```

I have posted my solution (a rewrite of the code linked to the first question) in: https://github.com/Utumno/so_34104763/commits/master. It's a nice exercise in refactoring - have a look at the commit messages. In particular I introduce the dict here: https://github.com/Utumno/so_34104763/commit/074b7e659282a9896ea11bbef770464d07e865b7

Could use more work but it's a step towards the right direction I think - should be faster too in most operations and conserve memory

Comment: I posted code to my first attempt prior to my post on here. Check it out. Hope it helps.

Comment: @JokerMartini: you should carry the relevant parts to your question - nobody will read and debug 300 lines of code for you for free ;)

Comment: Updated the question to show focus on the bits regarding the delete. I placed comments in the def tk explain. When I get to a computer today I'll try your solution. Let me know if my snippet needs further explaining.

Comment: @JokerMartini: I set up a repo to hack on it here: https://github.com/Utumno/so_34104763/commits/master. I still need some  incentive - cause it's a rewrite that's needed

Comment: I'll mark your answer correct since its the most logical approach ive been looking for. I don't have funds to pay you to rewrite it. I'll update and clean up my code and post it on github and link to it in the original post on here so others can see it.

Comment: @JokerMartini: Hahaha - I did not mean funds, in this place you pay with reputation - but hey I already rewrote it - check my new commits: https://github.com/Utumno/so_34104763/commits/master.

Comment: It is not production code of course (for instance the persons are duplicated in the tree nodes and the dict) - but it is a step to this direction ;) Note that tou need to make code as short and as readable as possible - avoid defining functions and module variables nilly wily - the less the merrier

Comment: Yeah i completely understand. I'm cleaning up the code i have right now. Could i then share that with you to see what it would cost for you to implement the 'rewrite'. I think it will be much easier with my cleaner code

Comment: Do have a look at my rewrite first - will save you some work ;)

Comment: Then yes I'd be interested :)

Comment: I will check it out. i don't want to fill this page with chat, you can email me or add me on gchat using jokermartini@gmail.com. Then when we come to a solution we can post it on here for the community.

Answer (score 2):

Not worrying too much about runtime or size of lists, you could use set-operations:

```
for p in set(original_list) - set(new_list):
    original_list.remove(p)
```

Or filter the list:

```
new_original_list = [p for p in original_list if p in new_list]
```

But then again, why look at the whole list - when one item (or even a non-leaf node in a tree) is deleted, you know which item was deleted, so you could restrict your search to just that one.

Comment: But by restricting to just the item deleted causes issues if that one child has a bunch of children leaf nodes. By just deleting the node which was removed doesn't signal in any way that their children were removed as well. Mean my list would still contain unused nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare objects using:

1. object identity
2. object equality

To compare objects identity you should use build in function **id()** or keyword **is** (that uses **id()**). From docs:

[id function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id)

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long
>   integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object
>   during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may
>   have the same id() value.

[is operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)

> The operators is and is not test for object identity: x is y is true
>   if and only if x and y are the same object. x is not y yields the
>   inverse truth value.

Example:

```
>>> p1 = Person('John')
>>> p2 = Person('Billy')
>>> id(p1) == id(p2)
False
>>> p1 is p2
False
```

To compare object equality you use **==** operator. **==** operator uses **eq** method to test for equality. If class does not define such method it falls back to comparing identity of objects.

So for:

> Or should I collect the uid numbers instead to do the comparisons
>   rather then the entire object?

you would be doing the same thing since you have not defined **eq** in your class.

To filter lists do not modify list while you are iterating over it is bad. Guess what will be printed:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2]
>>> for item in a:
...     if item in b:
...         a.remove(item)
>>> a
[2, 3]
```

If you want to do this safely iterate over list from the back like:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2]
>>> for i in xrange(len(a) - 1, -1, -1):
...     if a[i] in b:
...         a.pop(i)
2
1
>>> a
[3]
```